# ios - creating a relation in Realm migration

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm struggling with creating a migration in Realm. In the old schema I use to have classes like this

```
class A: Object {
    @dynamic var identifier = 0
    @dynamic var bID = 0
}

class B: Object {
    @dynamic var identifier = 0
}
```

Right now I'd love to create class A to look like this

```
class A: Object {
    @dynamic var identifier = 0
    @dynamic var b: B?
}
```

But I am unable to write a migration that would work.

UPDATE: What I'm trying to achieve is something like this

```
migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: A.className(), { (old, new) in
    guard let bID = old?["bID"] as? Int else {
        new?["b"] = nil
        return
    }
    new?["b"] = (try! Realm()).object(ofType: B.self, forPrimaryKey: bID)
})
```

Hope it is a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've found this github issue - https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1385 I assume it is not possible right now.

So my solution was to create a *migration dictionary* which contained information which relations should be created after the migration is performed and then create relations myself by calling `realm.write { }`.

If the original `bID` property won't be deleted the dictionary wouldn't be needed.

This is the code I created

```
var migrationDict = [Int: Int]()

let configuration = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 2, migrationBlock: { (migration, oldVersion) in
    if oldVersion < 2 { 
        migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: A.className(), { (old, new) in
            if let bID = old?["bID"] as? Int, let id = old?["identifier"] as? Int {
                migrationDict[id] = bID
            }
        }
    }
})

Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = configuration

let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    migrationDict.forEach { aID, bID in
        // set the A.b relation here
    }
}
```